# Related Rates (part2) $y=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y = \sqrt{x}$

a) Find $\frac{dy}{dt}$  when $x=4$ , Given $\frac {dx}{dt}=3$

I did

$$y = x^{1/2} \implies \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{dx}{dt}$$ then plugged in $x=4$ and $y=3$, but I am getting wrong solution

Comment: I formatted your previous question. Since this question is so similar, copy-and-pasting with changing some letters around would be a great first step into learning MathJax.

Comment: Can I see what you are putting as answer or can you show the work where you plug in please?

Comment: i got the answer now, small mistake on my end. thank you

Comment: are you getting something different from $\frac{3}{4}$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be $\frac{3}{4}$ based off of the work you have shewn.